# Unlimited users Wifi AP android mode (no ROOT privileges)

Tags: java, android, dhcp, tethering

I make an application that requieres WiFi AP-mode (DHCP Server and WiFI AP). which allows unlimited  simultaneously number of users (Android limit 10 users for tethering). Is there any code for it? Or ready application? I need to perform it without ROOT privileges

Answer (score 1):

The Android limit is hardcoded at a system level, and probably at a protocol level too.

Modifying it will at the very least require root privileges, and maybe even a direct rewrite of the Android code at the system level.

Comment: Well, so do you think there is no option how to make own JAVA app to make it work?

Comment: @MatejKultan Not without root *at the very least*. Increasing a network limit may require rewriting at a source level